# Review SVN commit in Eclipse

Tags: svn

I'm doing a java project with 4 other people. We use svn to do version control. Is there any way to check who has committed most of the programs? I have tried using sonar plug in for **eclipse**. But I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SVN client command line](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html).

If you do not have it already, for WIN it could be https://sliksvn.com/download/. For Linux, take a look at something like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/258151/how-to-install-subversion-client-in-ubuntu

After that, if you are on WIN, use this PowerShell command:

```
svn log --xml | select-string -pattern '<author>[\s\S]*?<\/author>' | Group-Object
```

If you are on Linux, use this shell command:

```
svn log -v --xml | grep '<author.*/author>' | sort $* | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

If you are on some else OS, Google for similar solutions, now you have the idea.

---

Btw: When you say *"But I cannot get it to work."* - when something is not working, you must provide more info about it, otherwise nobody can help you. Read a bit more about ["How to ask good question."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It will help you to get good answers.

Comment: Well I installed sonarqube for eclipse. I cannot see sonar in my preferences